# Is there a query application?

Tags: discussion, tools

I was wondering if there was any single query application which could take in the question of the person then send it to all open source help related sites like askubuntu.com, stackoverflow.com, askfedora.com, linuxquestions, then fetch with the results of those asked questions in a simple way? Is there a universal open source help portal application? Like we have a unity lens for Ask Ubuntu, can we have a lens which encompasses all such help sites?

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion that would create a lot of off-topic posts from users desperate to get answers and not considerate enough to not spam the sites that aren't appropriate for their questions. Crossposting is a rather annoying habit to have.

Comment: okay, thanx for the advice!